# change text "free shipping" in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Recently we give free shipping to all german customers but bill the austria and switzerland. On our product pages we show the free shipping, but as needed for german law, it must be called "free shipping in Germany". Where can I change this text?

Couldnt find a solution in WooCommerce setting nor in WooCommerce German Market Plugin. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this answer .
Hope this will help you.
maybe with wpml for multi-lang

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296093/woocommerce-free-shipping-remove-raw-or-change-the-text-name-on-checkout-and-e

Answer (score 0):

You need to check location first and then change the  display text or you can change the text from the back end. This [link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/free-shipping/) show you how.

Answer (score -2):

you can use css on this.
get the selector of free shipping. set display to hidden then use psuedo element :after to place the new text

You can use this filter. To change the shipping title. This would be SEO friendly.

```
function filter_woocommerce_shipping_package_name( $sprintf, $i, $package ) { 

    return $sprintf; 
}; 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_package_name', 'filter_woocommerce_shipping_package_name', 10, 3 );
```

Heres some reference

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_cart_totals_shipping_html.html#223

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

Comment: I had this in mind, but its not very secure for further updates. But thanks for this idea! Do you know it this is SEO-friendly?

Comment: yeah I think so, this is not seo friendly.